# Memory simulation in WPF: Binding byte array positions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, interpreter

I'm writing a language interpreter using C#. My user interface permits to visualize and change global variables and direct memory addresses in runtime.

I have problems when I try to visualize and change direct memory addresses as they can be visualized in different data sizes (BYTE, WORD and DWORD).

```
    0       1       2       3
---------------------------------
| FFx16 | FFx16 | FFx16 | FFx16 | Memory
---------------------------------
                        - BYTE 3-  
                ---- WORD 1 -----
------------ DWORD 0 ------------
```

So, If I'm visualizing BYTE3, WORD1 and DWORD0 in my UI, when I change value of BYTE3 my view doesn't upgrade WORD1 and DWORD0 values.

Memory and execution context (Model):

```
public class Memoria 
{
    private byte[] memoria;

    public Memoria(int size)
    {
        memoria = new byte[size];
    }

    public void Write<T>(int index, Tipo t, T value)
    {

        int nBytes = t.GetBytes();

        byte[] bytesArray = t.GetBytesArray(value);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytesArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++)
        {
            memoria[index+ i] = bytesArray[i];
        }
    }
}

public class Context
{
    public Memoria DataMem { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, IVariableObservable> VarGlobal { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<int, IVariableObservable> DirectAdress { get; private set; }

    public InsertValues ()
    {
        foreach (IVariableObservable v in VarGlobal.Values)
        {
            Action action = () => v.Valor = v.InitValue;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);

            v.InsertValue();
        }
    }

    public UpdateValue (int index)
    {
        IVariableObservable v = VarGlobal[index];
        v.UpdateValue();
        }
    }
}

// * Language interpreter types are represented in Tipo objects
public abstract class Tipo
{
    //* ....... More methods

    public virtual int GetBytes()
    {
       return 0;
    }

    // * UI Representation
    public virtual T GetUIRepresentation<T>(object valor)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(valor, typeof(T)); 
    }
}
```

Variable (Model):

```
public interface IVariableObservable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string Name { get; }

    Tipo Tipo { get; }  

    object Valor { get; set; }

    object InitValue { get; set; }

    int Offset { get; set; }

    Memoria DataMem { get; set; }

    void InsertValue()

    void UpdateValue();

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName);
}

public interface IVariableObservable<T> : IVariableObservable
{
    new T Valor { get; set; }

    new T InitValue { get; set; }
}

public class VariableObservable<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IVariableObservable<T>
{
    private T valor;

    public T Valor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.ToString() == this.valor.ToString())
                return;

            this.valor = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Valor");
        }
    }

    object IVariableObservable.Valor
    {
        get { return Valor; }
        set
        {
            Valor = Tipo.GetUIRepresentation<T>(value);                
        }
    }

    public Memoria DataMem { get; set; }

    public void InsertValue()
    {
        DataMem.Write<T>(Offset, Tipo, Valor);
    }

    public void UpdateValue()
    {
         Valor = DataMem.Read<T>(Offset, Tipo);
    }
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
    public class VariableViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
    {

        readonly IVariableObservable _variable;
        readonly ObserverRepository _observerRepository;

        public VariableViewModel(IVariableObservable variable, ObserverRepository observerRespository)
        {
            if (variable == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("variable");

            if (observerRespository == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("observerRespository");

            _variable = variable;
            _observerRepository = observerRespository;

            this._variable.PropertyChanged += this.OnVariableValueChanged;
        }

        private void OnVariableValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Valor");
        }

        public object Valor
        {
            get
            {
                return _variable.Valor;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _variable.Valor) 
                    return; 

                _variable.Valor = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Valor");               
                _variable.InsertValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to check changes in the different memory positions and propagate changes to all memory addresses which share those memory positions?

Comment: your setter for your Valor property looks not right for me. you just call .toString() and this should just work right for string type... and so 

> this.OnPropertyChanged("Valor");

 would never be called. if you override .ToString() in a way that your 

> if ((value == _variable.Valor) || (value.ToString() == ""))

is satisfied right then it could work.

Comment: you're right as (value.ToString()=="") is not necessary, but I think it's not relevant because the setter of Valor is working fine and this.OnPropertyChanged("Valor") is called (and UI upgraded). Visualization and changes in globals variables work perfectly for me, the problem are direct memory addresses which share same memry positions.

Comment: @Jessica Tipo definition added. Updated (value.ToString()=="")  as blindmeis said.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to reason about your code due to the hidden extra complexity in your code. I'm working on some code that you should be able to adapt to answer your real question about updating variables that share the same memory address.

Comment: I've gotten some working code but I just wanted to check with you your requirements for monitoring the memory? My code at present works like the watch window in a debugger. You define some variables to watch and anytime the memory for those variables change they are updated. It also supports partially overlapping variables. Is this the behaviour you were looking for?

Comment: @Jessica this is exactly the behauviour i'm looking for...  if you are tracking two different variables whose values are allocated in a memory byte, when you make a change in that memory byte, both variable values will be update in the view. (note that byte changed could be only one of the bytes that represent the value of the variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so as discussed in comments I didn't fix your code so much as re-write it entirely to use a different architecture that I think will work better for you assuming it doesn't break other functionality you require.

The main goal of my code was to make it so variables didn't keep copies of their values but instead looked to the memory store itself when retrieving the value and likewise using the memory store to set its value.

All variables store is a 'pointer' to a memory location (an address within a IMemory object). The IMemory object provides Read and Write operations to read and write one or more contiguous bytes from/to the memory.

IMemory exposes a MemoryChanged event which fires whenever a Write operation occurs. Variables attached themselves to this event in their constructor and upon receiving the event they check whether any of the changed addresses cover any part of the variable. If they do then the variable fires its INotifyPropertyChanged event which can be use by WPF et al to monitor for variable updates.

And now the code:

```
public interface IMemory
{
    void Write(int address, params byte[] bytes);
    byte[] Read(int address, int numBytes);
    byte Read(int address);
    event MemoryChangedEventHandler MemoryChanged;
}

public class Memory : IMemory
{
    private readonly byte[] _memory;

    public Memory(int size)
    {
        _memory = new byte[size];
    }

    public void Write(int address, params byte[] bytes)
    {
        for (int offset = 0; offset < bytes.Length; offset++)
        {
            _memory[address + offset] = bytes[offset];
        }

        UpdateMemory(address, bytes.Length);
    }

    public byte[] Read(int address, int numBytes)
    {
        return _memory.Skip(address).Take(numBytes).ToArray();
    }

    public byte Read(int address)
    {
        return _memory[address];
    }

    private void UpdateMemory(int address, int length)
    {
        if (MemoryChanged != null)
        {
            MemoryChanged(this, new MemoryChangedEventArgs
            {
                StartAddress = address,
                EndAddress = address + length
            });
        }
    }

    public event MemoryChangedEventHandler MemoryChanged;
}

public delegate void MemoryChangedEventHandler(object sender, MemoryChangedEventArgs e);

public class MemoryChangedEventArgs
{
    public int StartAddress { get; set; }
    public int EndAddress { get; set; }
}

public class IntVariable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly int _address;
    private readonly Memory _memory;

    public IntVariable(int address, Memory memory)
    {
        _address = address;
        _memory = memory;

        _memory.MemoryChanged += MemoryChanged;
    }

    private void MemoryChanged(object sender, MemoryChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int startAddress = _address;
        int endAddress = startAddress + sizeof (int);

        int changedStartAddress = e.StartAddress;
        int changedEndAddress = e.EndAddress;

        if (IsVariableChanged(startAddress, changedStartAddress, endAddress, changedEndAddress))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsVariableChanged(int startAddress, int changedStartAddress, int endAddress, int changedEndAddress)
    {
        return Math.Max(startAddress, changedStartAddress) <= Math.Min(endAddress, changedEndAddress);
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            var intBytes = _memory.Read(_address, sizeof(int));
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(intBytes, 0);
        }
        set
        {
            var intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            _memory.Write(_address, intBytes);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

So you would construct your Memory object then create IntVariable (obviously you would create different variable types as required for your different visualisations) objects that reference the Memory object and an address within the memory.

E.g.

```
var _memory = new Memory(20);
var variable1 = new IntVariable(0, _memory);
var variable2 = new IntVariable(0, _memory);
```

Then doing `variable1.Value = 4;` would make variable1 and variable2 fire their INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: As an afterthought this handily will update the variables even if you don't change a variable's value through a xxxVariable type object but instead directly write to the memory store with Write.

Comment: Thank you for time. I have to adapt this idea to my code, but I think it would work. I will tell you if I succeed or not. Thanks again ;)

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you. If you're happy with my answer I'd appreciate it if you'd mark it as the accepted answer to your question :)